# Jooq and PSQLException

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I am trying to fetch records with nasted childs in it but get PSQLException syntax error and org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException.

```
        record ChildRecord(Integer parentId) {}
        record ParentRecord(Integer parentId, List<ChildRecords> childs) {};


        List<ParentRecord> parents dsl.select(ParentTable.ID,
                        multiset(
                                select(ChildTable.ID)
                                        .from(ChildTable)
                                        .where(Parent.ID
                                                .eq(Child.PARENT_ID)))

                                .as("childs")
                                .convertFrom(records -> records.map(Records.mapping(ChildRecord::new))))
                .from(ParentTable)
                .fetchInto(ParentRecord.class);
        return parents;
    }
```

To make note using Java records with very limited info selected just to make this working.
But geting stacktrase:

```
org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [...]ERROR: syntax error at or near "select"
  Position: 56
    at org.jooq_3.18.0.DEFAULT.debug(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools.translate(Tools.java:3465) ~[jooq-3.18.0.jar:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools.translate(Tools.java:3453) ~[jooq-3.18.0.jar:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultExecuteContext.sqlException(DefaultExecuteContext.java:765) ~[jooq-3.18.0.jar:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:371) ~[jooq-3.18.0.jar:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetchLazy(AbstractResultQuery.java:301) ~[jooq-3.18.0.jar:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetchLazyNonAutoClosing(AbstractResultQuery.java:322) ~[jooq-3.18.0.jar:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.SelectImpl.fetchLazyNonAutoClosing(SelectImpl.java:2862) ~[jooq-3.18.0.jar:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.ResultQueryTrait.collect(ResultQueryTrait.java:360) ~[jooq-3.18.0.jar:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.ResultQueryTrait.fetchInto(ResultQueryTrait.java:1434) ~[jooq-3.18.0.jar:na]
......
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:891) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1784) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "select"
```

Using
JOOQ 18.0
Postgres 14.5
Spring Boot v2.7.8, Spring v5.3.25
Java 17.0.5

Where I am wrong in this query?

Comment: Can you post the complete generated SQL query so we can see what is wrong about it?

Comment: org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [select "schema_name"."parent"."parent_id", multiset(select "schema_name"."child"."parent_id" from "schema_name"."child" where "schema_name"."child"."parent_id" = "schema_name"."parent"."parent_id") "childs" from "schema_name"."parent"]; ERROR: syntax error at or near "select"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key line of your stack trace is this one:

```
at org.jooq_3.18.0.DEFAULT.debug(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

The `SQLDialect.DEFAULT` is used to render SQL, instead of `SQLDialect.POSTGRES`, which you should use to run queries on PostgreSQL.